# ArrayList iteration specific list

Tags: java, list, loops, arraylist

I have an arraylist in which

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listofItems=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

in the list of items I have items like this

[[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14][15][16][17][18][19][20][21][22]]

how to iterate and store in another array these values split into two like

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] and [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]. I have used advanced for loop

```
for(ArrayList<String> list:listofItems)
{

for (String s:list)
{

//I dont know how to add logic here.

}

}
```

Comment: On what basis you are splitting the values?

Comment: Is 11 supposed to be in both lists?

Comment: what are the constraints ?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to tell. Is your arraylist contains list of string? If yes then you can do it easily. Just write it clearly with clear example.

Comment: @khelwood yes 11 to be in both lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming here that both lists will also hold string type data.If you want Integer type,you can parse while adding.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listofItems = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (ArrayList<String> list : listofItems) {

                for (String s : list) {
                    // there shud be some condition how much elements you want in a
                    // list or some condition
                    // to decide in which list we need to add item
                    if (list.size() < 12)
                        list1.add(s);
                    else
                        list2.add(s);

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like that:

```
if (yourlist.size()>0) {
   List<String> first = yourList.subList(0, (int)Math.ceil(yourlist.size()/2.0));
   List<String> second = yourList.subList((int)Math.ceil(yourlist.size()/2.0), yourlist.size());
}
```

Would be separate your list in 2 lists divided in the half.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to store your list into another list.

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(ArrayList<String> list:listofItems) {
  for (String s:list) {
    stringList.add(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, when you add info to listOfItems, you should try example like this

```
    for(int i = 0; i< 2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            /// add util break n
            lists.get(i).add(strTemp);
        }
    }
```

You can change `i < 2` into any number you want. I only make this sample for you.